# Parse.com android relationship

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse.com for my app. I need help to solve this scenario. I have two tables say

> category table

with n number of category and

> product table

with n number of products. Now how can i set the relation between category and products. A product may comes in more than one category. Say productX may comes under categoryA and also categoryB. Should i use pointer or relation. Can any one provide a good example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For almost all your relationships, a pointer is all you need. However, a pointer column can only include 1 objectId, so in your case you need to create the column as an array, and store pointers in the array.

Further reading:

https://www.parse.com/questions/array-of-pointer

https://www.parse.com/questions/update-array-of-pointer-column

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-query-a-pointer-array-column